# Ocaml - string to (int*int*int) list

Tags: string, list, int, ocaml

Is in ocaml function which can parse string like this "[(1,2,3);(1,2,5);(2,3,4)]" into (int*int*int) list ? or do I have to write my own parsing function ?

Thanks

Greg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it should not be too difficult with help of the [Scanf](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Scanf.html) module from the standard library -- you will be able to scan the triples easily and then only have to add a bit of logic to parse a list.

Alternatively you can take a look at [deriving](http://code.google.com/p/deriving/):

> Extension to OCaml for deriving functions from type declarations. Includes derivers for pretty-printing, type-safe marshalling with structure-sharing, dynamic typing, equality, and more.

Comment: thanks, I did it in this way, not so beauty but works ;)


    let rec parse_string s = 
      match s with 
        | _ when String.length s > 7 -> 
     (Scanf.sscanf (String.sub s 1 7) "(%i,%i,%i)" (fun a b c ->     (a,b,c)))::(parse_string (String.sub s 8 ((String.length s)-8)))
        |_ -> [];;

Answer (score 4):

If you're willing to use a somewhat different format, you can have your parser for free.  Using the sexplib syntax extension, you can simply write:

```
type t = (int * int * int) list with sexp
```

and this will automatically define for you two functions, `sexp_of_t` and `t_of_sexp`.  Sexplib also provides multiple parsing functions.

The concrete syntax of s-expressions, however, is different.  Your example would be rendered:

```
((1 2 3) (1 2 5) (2 3 4))
```